# Rails Rendering Show in Bootstrap Modal from index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carrierwave

I’m trying to render “show” via Bootstrap Modal from photos index page.
 Intended photo (unploaded with carrierwave) shows up correctly if I use the show page direct `(..\views\photos\show.html.erb)` without rendering via bootstrap modal.

But the problem is photo doesn’t show when I try to render with `_show.html.erb.` However the fallback image shows up even with any available hard coded texts within `_show.html.erb.` Below are the snippets;

```
    views\photos\_show.html.erb

`<% if @photo.image? %>
  <%= image_tag @photo.image.url(:thumb2) %> #this is the intended photo
  <% else %>
  <%= image_tag("fallback/default.png") %>
  <% end %>`

    Photos_controller.rb

`def show
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @photo }
  end
end`


`views\photos\index.html.erb`  for Bootstrap modal

    <div class =”..”>
    <% if photo.image? 
    <%# Added Bootstrap data modal attribute %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:thumb)), '#showModal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>

    <div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Showing photo</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= render 'show' %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

photo.js

 $("#showModal").click(function(){
    $("#show").modal();
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how to debug javascript with your browser?  If not, what browser are you using?  If so, do any errors come out on your browser console?

Comment: @neanderslob - I’m using Firefox but no error is showing in the js source codes. No changes are recorded in the “Network” as well when the localhost:3000/photos#showModal is opened. Still shows
Request URL:  http://localhost:300/photos
Request method: Get
Status code: 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Wasn't a javascript issue ruby instead.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

In the index page, I changed <%= render 'show' %> to
<%= render :partial => 'show', :locals => { :photo => photo } %>
and then changed @photo in _show.html.erb to photo which makes it a local variable in the index page.